# Unable to create CONSTRAINT ON ( ___neo4jgraphs:___neo4jgraphs )

Tags: apache-spark, neo4j

I am trying to store a graph created from ***Spark-dataframes*** with the project [Cypher-for-Apache-Spark](https://github.com/opencypher/cypher-for-apache-spark) into ***neo4j***.

When i run my code: [**which you can find it in the last comment in an issue in github**](https://github.com/opencypher/cypher-for-apache-spark/issues/579)

i get this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.DatabaseException: Unable to create CONSTRAINT ON ( ___neo4jgraphs874:___neo4jgraphs874 ) ASSERT ___neo4jgraphs874.___morpheusID IS UNIQUE:
Both Node(57) and Node(74) have the label `___neo4jgraphs874` and property `___morpheusID` = 4
```

any one knows why that happen ?

Comment: I think the error is pretty clear ....you have two nodes with the same `id` so the constraint can't be applied

Comment: did you know how to fix it ? "the _morpheusID" in the  CAPS project if you have used it before ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved [here](https://github.com/opencypher/cypher-for-apache-spark/issues/599)
I 've figured out what is the problem:
this error is fired because the dataframes have the same id numbers :

```
df1||df2||df3
 0L||0L ||0L
 1L||1L ||1L
 2L||2L ||2L
```

to be fixed each dataframe need to have it's id differents from the other :

```
df1||df2||df3
0L||3L  ||6L
1L||4L  ||7L
2L||5L  ||8L
```